# How to edit or alter Spring parameter expansion?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

In application.yml:

```
flyway:
  locations: classpath:/db/migration, classpath:/db/local
  placeholders:
    csvpath: ${user.dir}/src/main/resources/db/local
```

In flyway init script:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${csvpath}/data.csv'
INTO TABLE myscheama.t1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The ${user.dir} expands to the path of the current project (what I desire), but on a Windows box that expands with path separators of '\'.  When Spring Boot spins up, flyway executes right away passing the expanded path to my DB (MySQL), which will not accept '\' in the path name.  How can I force a '/' instead or get the proper slash in my path to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by implementing an EnvironmentPostProcessor:

1. Add a `META-INF/spring.factories` properties file to `src/main/resources`

   ```
   # Environment Post Processor 
   org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor = com.gitlab.ttubbs.myapp.PropertiesEnvironmentPostProcessor
   ```
2. Add implementation:

   ```
   package com.gitlab.ttubbs.myapp;

   import java.util.Map;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
   import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
   import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
   import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;
   import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

   public class PropertiesEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor
   {

       private static final String SYSTEM_PROPERTIES = "systemProperties";
       private static final String USER_DIR         = "user.dir";
       private static final char   BACKSLASH        = '\\';
       private static final char   FORWARD_SLASH    = '/';

       @Override
       public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
           MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
           Map<String, Object> systemProperties = getMapPropertySource(propertySources, SYSTEM_PROPERTIES);

           // Update ${user.dir} to use FORWARD_SLASH instead of BACKSLASH
           updateMapProperty(systemProperties, USER_DIR, environment.getProperty(USER_DIR).replace(BACKSLASH, FORWARD_SLASH));
       }

       private Map<String, Object> getMapPropertySource(MutablePropertySources propertySources, String sourceName) {
           if (propertySources.contains(sourceName)) {
               PropertySource<?> source = propertySources.get(sourceName);
               if (source instanceof MapPropertySource) {
                   MapPropertySource target = (MapPropertySource) source;
                   return target.getSource();
               }
           }

           return null;
       }

       private void updateMapProperty(Map<String, Object> target, String key, String value) {
           if(target != null) {
               target.put(key, value);
           }
       }
   }
   ```